# iPhone app maps current user location GIF

Tags: ios, image, gif

Anybody know a way to get the *Current user location* icon that apple uses? Or anyone know if anybody recreated an animated one?

Thanks!

Comment: that's a good question, did you find anything? I am also looking for something similar, but it is really difficult to find any resources. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution which comes close to how Apple does it, I created a static png image (transparent animated gifs are ugly). And then using the map API to draw a circle with a transparency under that icon.

Here's the static png that I use:
[image: static marker image]

Comment: Could you make that GIF public available?

Comment: I realised that gifs with transparency are ugly. So I simply used a static png over a dynamically rendered transparent circle for the radius.